# Get first element that does not contain value in an array in cypress

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress, end-to-end

I have a list of cards and I need to programmatically select the first in the list that does not contain one of five values that I have in an array.  I have tried this:

```
cy.get('.parent-element').not().contains('string1', 'string2', 'etc')
```

and this:

```
cy.get('.parent-element').not('string1', 'string2', 'etc')
```

hmmm. any thoughts on this.  any child element of `.parent-element` is fair game except for these few exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const selector = ".parent-element li";
const array = ["string1", "string2", "string3"];
cy.get(selector)
  .then($els => {
    return $els.filter((i, el) => {
      // Cypress.$ is jQuery
      const textContent = Cypress.$(el).text();
      const result = array.filter(str => textContent.includes(str));
      // if noone string is been found... we have found the desired element
      return !result.length;
    });
  })
  .then($el => {
    // $el is your searched element

    // some assertions about it
    expect($el.text()).not.includes("string1");
    expect($el.text()).not.includes("string2");
    expect($el.text()).not.includes("string3");
  });
```

- specify the selector to find the children (I appended `li` to the selector)
- the `.not().contains` you were using are assertions, not filters
- the `cy.get` function returns some jquery elements
- use `Cypress.$` (that is jQuery) to filter out manually the various children

Let me know if it's enough clear

Answer (score 0):

I used not command like this :

```
cy.get('.alert-radio-group > button')
.not(`:contains(\'${valueSelected1}\')`)
.not(`:contains(\'${valueSelected2}\')`)
.first()
.click();
```